# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class XXXXX shouldest multiple JSON fields named XXXX

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I'm consuming a REST service (and I do not have access to his code) that returns me a JSON like this:

```
{
  "Type1": {
    "id": "1"
    },
  "Type2": {
      "id": 2
    },
  "Type3": {
      "id": 2
    }
  }
```

When you attempt to deserialization an error occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class XXXXX shouldest multiple JSON fields named id
```

How can I turn this Json object without changing the code that generates this JSON?

Comment: How are you deserializing this?

Comment: Yes. I´m trying to deserializing. I can´t change anything on serializing.

Comment: What we meant is show us some code where you're deserializing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it all together, iterate through each "Type" object at once  maybe convert the whole Json to string and break it into multiple Json objects like this  `{"Type1": {"id": "1" }}` then do the same for the next "Type" `{"Type2": {"id": "1" }}`

Answer (score 0):

I just found the error. I was my mistake I was trying to make a `gson.fromJson(type3)` using a wrong type class.

Thanks everybody!